End of Free Trial Period on Meet Up group
I set up a free trial period of 30 days on my Meet Up that ended yesterday to pay dues by May 23 to stay in the group. Why haven't unpaid members been removed from future events they were signed up for? Does it take the site a few days to enact this? I set the process up right with Stripe account first. Next to members names I still see Free Trial expires May 23, 2024. I thought that message would be changed for them to Awaiting dues payment

Welcome to Web Applications. Consider registering your account to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. Registering is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see Why should I register my account?
